# JavaScript basis is a decimal number in math.pow function

Tags: javascript, php, regex, math

My problem: Within a PHP Function Code should be prepared for an export in JavaScript. So I have this row:

```
$operationvalue_new2 = preg_replace_("#exp\((.*)\^(.*)\)#", "Math.pow($1, $2)", $operationvalue_new2);
```

Problem is now the value of `$1` can be a decimal, so I will not calculate correctly anymore. If `$1` would be 1.2 it is only calculating with 1.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues I see with your regex:

- The double-quoted string might make escaping the string with backslashes less effective, since regular expressions need to be escaped themselves: Try using double-quoted backslashes:

  ```
  "#exp\\((.*)\\^(.*)\\)#"
  ```
- The `.*` matches as much as possible. But that includes cases such as `exp(1,4);exp(2^4)`. Use non-greedy matches or exclude the characters not needed:

  ```
  "#exp\\(([^\\^\\)]*)\\^([^\\^\\)]*)\\)#"
  ```
- Furthermore, matching any arbitrary text, even with that fix, is risky, especially if the resulting text will be part of generated JavaScript code. Consider, for example, what would happen if the text contained `exp(</script>^5)`. Instead, match only well-formed numbers if that is the intent:

  ```
  "#exp\\((\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\)#"
  ```